# Defining a C array where every element is the same memory location

Tags: c++, c, arrays

In C (or C++), is it possible to create an array `a` (or something that "looks like" an array), such that `a[0]`, `a[1]`, etc., all point to the *same* memory location? So if you do

```
a[0] = 0.0f;
a[1] += 1.0f;
```

then `a[0]` will be equal to `1.0f`, because it's the same memory location as `a[1]`.

I do have a reason for wanting to do this. It probably isn't a good reason. Therefore, please treat this question as if it were asked purely out of curiosity.

I should have said: I want to do this without overloading the [] operator. The reason for this has to do with avoiding a dynamic dispatch. (I already told you my reason for wanting to do this is probably not a good one. There's no need to tell me I shouldn't want to do it. I already know this.)

Comment: No, then it's not an array. It would also be very confusing to understand what's happening, probably even for you when you come back to this in a few months time.

Comment: A union is a similar concept. When you use a union, you refer to the same memory location with different member names. So you could define the members of your union to be 2 different arrays

Comment: @molbdnilo: Have you ever tried `#define 1 0`?

Comment: `I want to do this without overloading the [] operator. The reason for this has to do with avoiding a dynamic dispatch.` It doesn't need to involve a dynamic dispatch...

Comment: What do you mean with “dynamic dispatch” and what does it have to do with a user-defined `operator[]`? There isn’t necessarily any overhead due to indirection (virtual method call), see [lisyarus’ aswer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22091817/1231686).

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean with "looks like an array"?

Comment: @Lumen there will be overhead if I want the object to sometimes be (or behave like) an actual array, and sometimes be one if these things, and I want the code that handles it not to care. To do this the "correct" way, they would derive from a virtual base class, incurring overhead on every call to operator[], which I want to avoid.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oops. And I usually say "first think, then type" myself...

Comment: @mvw see my above comment I guess. I want the code not to care if its accessing an array or a single memory location, and I don't want the overhead of a virtual method call. (I should have asked for that directly, but I was hoping there would be some low level C pointer trick that could do it.)

Comment: @Lightless see my comment to molbdnilo

Comment: @Nathaniel: I don't see how virtual dispatch would be "the 'correct' way".

Comment: Re "I want the code not to care if its accessing an array or a single memory location" I would need example intended code to grok this.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose a class like this is what you need

```
template <typename T>
struct strange_array
{
   T & operator [] (int) { return value; }
private:
   T value;
};
```

Comment: Isn’t it enough to return a reference to `value`?

Comment: @Lumen: Sure, but, there is no way to give `value` a .. y'know, value. As it stands in this answer, `strange_array` will always give you a reference to a default-initialised object. So that seems pretty useless. I suggest that `strange_array` be given a constructor.

Comment: @Lumen: Wait, yes, you're absolutely right, of course. :) Never mind me

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: you can set the value like this `a[<any-int-index>] = <your-desired-value>;`

Comment: @lisyarus: See previous comment

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: yup, I see :)

Answer (score 2):

You can always define an array of pointers which points towards the same variable :

```
typedef int* special;
int i = 0;
unsigned int var = 0xdeadbeef;
special arr[5];

for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    arr[i] = &var;

*(arr[0]) = 0;
*(arr[3]) += 3;

printf("%d\n", *(arr[2]));
// -> 3
```

Comment: I will probably end up doing this. The disadvantage is that gcc will never be able to auto-vectorize my code, but realistically there's probably no way around that.

Answer (score 0):

In C, I don't think so.

The expression `a[i]` simply means `*(a + i)`, so it's hard to avoid the addition due to the indexing.

You might be able to glue something together by making `a` (the array name) a macro, but I'm not sure how: you wouldn't have access to the index in order to compensate for it.

Answer (score 0):

Without overloading `operator[]`?

**No, it's not possible.**

Fortunately.

Answer (score 0):

From all that conversation here, I now understand the problem as follows:

You want to have the syntax of an array, e.g.

```
a[n]     // only lookup 
a[n]++   // lookup and write
```

but you want to have the semantics changed to all of those map to the same element, like

```
a[0]
a[0]++
```

The C++ way to achieve this is IMHO to overload the index access operator [].
But, you don't want it for performance reasons.

I join the opinon of user Lightness Races in Orbit that you can not do this within C++.

As you don't provide more information about the use case it is hard to come up with a solution.
Best I can imagine is that you have lots of written code which uses array semantics which you can not change.

What is left (wanting to keep performance) are code transformation techniques (CPP, sed, ..), generating a source code from the given source code with the desired behaviour, e.g. by forcing all index values to 0.

Comment: I don't care about the syntax, I just want to avoid the overhead. I was hoping a low level C pointer hack would do the job, but evidently not. I will post a less dumb question about my actual use case in die course.